# Background different sizes on different pages

Tags: html, css, background

See the background here:

http://www.achingsoul.co.uk/gallery/

It's applied to the body element and correctly-sized. But when you look at it here:

http://www.achingsoul.co.uk/services/

It's stretched out and very strange-looking. I'm not sure what it is as the CSS for it is the same on both pages according to inspector:

```
body {
    background-image: url('images/aching-soul-background-2.jpg');
    color: #4a2f1f;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Not sure what it is I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `background-size: cover;` 
Your background won't stretch anymore, instead, it will repeat vertically. 
The difference between both pages is caused by the greater height in the services page, when you use the cover value for the background-size property, it will cause this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try `background-position:50% 50%;`

and also

```
`/* FOR A LARGE-SINGLE IMAGE TO STRETCH COMFORTABLY ACROSS A BODY*/
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
    zoom:1;`
```